# Defining a command to generate a sequence

Tags: loops

I'm trying to define a command to make a list of subscripted `\varphi` characters.  Let's call it `\phiseq`.  I want to be able to use `\phiseq{1,2,3}` in the body of my document to expand to `$\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3$`.  Any ideas?  I've tried several experiments with `\@for`, but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\phiseq#1{$\let\comma\@empty\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\comma\varphi_{\tmp}\def\comma{,}}$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\phiseq{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently I need to learn more about `\makeatletter`!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can define a fairly general command with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kellvyn_print_seq:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% #1 = input delimiter
  % #2 = output delimiter
  % #3 = symbol
  % #4 = list
  % store the list in a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_kellvyn_args_seq { #1 } { #4 }
  % clear the auxiliary sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l_kellvyn_print_seq
  % process the argument list
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_kellvyn_args_seq
   {
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \dots }
     {% if the item is \dots, store it unchanged
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kellvyn_print_seq { \dots }
     }
     {% otherwise, store "symbol_{item}"
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kellvyn_print_seq { #3\sb{##1} }
     }
   }
  % print the sequence
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_kellvyn_print_seq { #2 } { #2 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\phiseq}{m}
 {
  \kellvyn_print_seq:nnnn { , } { , }{ \varphi } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printseq}{O{,}mm}
 {
  \kellvyn_print_seq:nnnn { , } { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\phiseq{1,2,3}$

$\phiseq{1,2,\dots,n}$

$\printseq{x}{1,2,\dots,k-1,k}$

$\printseq[;]{y}{1,2,3,4}$
\end{document}
```

With `\phiseq` you get your original request, but with the bonus that a `\dots` input will produce dots in the output. The `\printseq` command is more general, the optional argument is the output delimiter. I've used also a parameter for the input delimiter for possible extensions (it's not more difficult to have it, so better be as general as possible).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@phiseqfirst
\def\phiseq#1{%
  \@phiseqfirsttrue
  $\@for\ind:=#1\do{
    \if@phiseqfirst\else,\fi
    \varphi_{\ind}
  \@phiseqfirstfalse}$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\phiseq{1,2,3,4}
\end{document}
```

The `\@phiseqfirst` magic is here to get rid of the spurious comma in the end (thanks to @GonzaloMedina for noting it).

Comment: In the output, there will be a spurious comma after the last term.

Comment: Thanks.  Did not see it.  I've added some code to prevent it.

Comment: You can use the kernel provided `\if@tempswa`, since `\@for` doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution with `pgffor`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def\seq#1#2{%
  \foreach \i[count = \j] in {#2}{%
    \unless\ifnum\j=1\relax, \fi$#1_{\i}$}}
\def\phiseq#1{\seq{\phi}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\seq{\psi}{1,...,5}\par
\phiseq{10,...,20}
\end{document}
```

[image]